# Хранение диапазонов времени и работа с ними в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, в которой хранятся объявления на неком сайте.
Объявления добавляются пользователями и публикуются по очереди с помощью CRON

```
`id` | `text` | `start` | `end` | `admin`
```

`start` - время, в которое объявление будет опубликовано
`end` - время, до которого объявление будет висеть "в топе"

При добавлении объявления скрипт находит MAX(`end`) и считает его временем публикации добавляемого объявления, `end` считается как start+некое число (например, 10 минут).

Здесь кажется все просто.

НО. Некоторые пользователи имеют привилегии самостоятельно выбрать время start и end. Например, назначить свою публикацию на завтра, на 12 часов для, и оставить ее в топе до 13 часов.
Здесь сталкиваюсь с проблемой - нужно проверить, нет ли на это время запланированных других "привелегированных" записей (с `admin`=1), если есть - оповестить об этом. Кроме этого, нужно сместить запланированные "обычные" записи  (c `admin`=0), если они есть в выбранном диапазоне.

Например, есть записи c end/start

```
12:00/12:10 | 12:10/12:20 | 12:20/12:30  | 12:30/12:40
```

Админ ставит свою запись на 12:12 с `end` = 12:40, тогда записи должны "выстроиться" в таком порядке:

```
12:00/12:10 | **12:12/12:40** |12:40/12:50 | 12:50/13:00  | 13:00/13:10
```

Есть ли у MySQL реализации для работы с подобными вещами? Правильный ли подход использую в целом?
Прошу помощи специалистов

Comment: *тогда записи должны "выстроиться" в таком порядке* - то есть все существующие записи - подвинуть? А если среди них есть "привилегированные записи" - что делать с ними? включая случай, когда вставляемая привилегированная запись пересекается по диапазону с уже существующей другой привилегированной? *Правильный ли подход использую в целом?* В данной задаче - скорее нет, чем да. Предметная область - чистая FIFO-очередь, связный список, с возможностью вставки в середину очереди, и соответственно структуру и алгоритмы надо брать под очередь заточенные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Часто трудности при реализации являются следствием того, что мы не достаточно хорошо понимаем задачу. Давайте на минуту отложим реализацию и вернёмся к задаче.

Во-первых, из сказанного вами следует, что для простых пользователей вы хотите помещать объявление в топ как можно раньше. Нет смысла планировать (считать max(end)) время публикации, важно запланировать только очерёдность.

Во-вторых, вы хотите дать привилегированным пользователям возможность "пройти без очереди". Обратите внимание, что такие пользователи тоже могут образовать очередь, если у них равные привелегии.

В-третьих, вы хотите предложить привилегированным пользователям ещё одну услугу -- возможность назначить время, когда они хотят разместить объявление.

Теперь можно подумать о том, как организовать публикацию объявлений. Переходим к реализации.

Вам понадобится две очереди бизнес и эконом. Ваш воркер публикации сперва смотрит есть ли кто-то в бизнес-очереди, если никого, тогда в эконом. Берёт первое в очереди объявление и публикует его в топе на время публикации. Это решает часть задачи, которая связана с публикацией.

Для части про назначение времени публикации понадобится расписание и отдельный воркер. Этот воркер заглядывает в расписание и помещает объявления в бизнес-очередь.

Смотрите что получается, если два админа запланируют публикацию на одно и то же время, то они могут получить предупреждение о конфликте при добавлении задачи в расписание. Если проигнорировать предупреждение, то объявления админов образуют очередь -- сперва будет показано объявление первого, затем второго.

Если на момент публикации бизнес-объявления в топе уже висит другое объявление, то бизнес-объявление дождётся завершения публикации текущего. Или вы можете предусмотреть прерывание текущего объявления.

Никаких тёмных пятен, всегда ясно что нужно делать. Очереди можно организовать как таблицы в бд, воркеров — через крон. Или используйте специальные инструменты типа gearman, rabbitmq.

---

Вот очень простая реализация для случая, если кодом отображающим топ владеете тоже вы.

Воркер публикации заменяется скриптом топа. Для топа создаётся табличка:

| businessId | economyId | announcement | till |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 345 | {text: ..., duration: ...} | 2022.11.02 19:00 |

Скрипт топа выбирает всегда единственную в вашем случае запись из этой таблички и смотрит не протух ли топ. Если топ свежий, то скрипт отображает его. Если топ стух, то скрипт лезет в business-очередь where id > businessId, и если такого нет то в economy-очередь where id > economyId. Потом обновляет свою запись в табличке и отображает свежий топ.

Таблички очередей очень простые:

| id | announcement |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {text: ..., duration: ...} |

Обычные пользователи публикуют объявления сразу в табличку economy-очереди. А привилегированные в табличку расписания. Крон-воркер стартует каждую минуту и если время пришло, публикует объявление из таблички расписания в табличку business-очереди.

Табличка расписания может быть такой:

| announcement | pubTime | done |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {text: ..., duration: ...} | 2022.12.31 23:59 | false |

Comment: Благодарю за ценную помощь! Действительно, много встало на свои места в плане постройки алгоритма. Если правильно понимаю, вы предлагаете сделать три таблицы - очередь стандартная, очередь бизнес, и расписание. Полагаю, что в одной таблице все же хранить данные будет легче. Потому как имея "стандартные" записи скажем на 12:00, 12:10, 12:20 при вставке "бизнес" записи на 12:10 - все равно придется обновить - либо время, либо ID этих записей..

Comment: Понял.. Для "Обычных" записей вообще нет смысла хранить время публикации - просто публиковать их тогда, когда нет "бизнес" записей. (хотя хотелось пользователя уведомлять о времени выхода его "обычной" записи, ну не столь принципиально). Время важно только для "бизнес" - им и занимаемся. Спасибо, Егор! Жму руку и очень ценю потраченное Вами время!